# Connect iOS 7 device with Xcode 4.6 for debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I learnt from somewhere that if i update my apple device to iOS 7 it would not be able to connect it with Xcode 4.6 for debugging. But I am able to use my iPod 5 running iOS 7 with Xcode 4.6, used it to debug my code. Most of the time Xcode do not connect with device but sometimes it do. 
Please advise what kind of problem it can be?

Answer (score 5):

When you update your device with iOS7 or any newest iOS which are not suporting the old version of Xcode but when you open it with new version of Xcode you are able to access it. Once you do so than it run on your older version of Xcode too and you can easily test your app using old version of Xcode.

Comment: This is straight forward case and i am sure about it. but what i am saying is that
I have mac OSX 10.7.5
XCode 4.6, iOS7 running device and sometimes i am able to connect

Comment: what i am thinking is when you are not using xcode5 that mens your not able to run your app on your device which running with iOS7 but in your case it happening somthing strange if it running with Xcode 4.6 :)...but even if you once connect your device with xcode5 it run with xcode4.6 too.

Comment: Yesssss....! its strange. I was curious to know the reason and i am curios to know if someone else is having same case.

Comment: you have xcode5??? or you use xcode5 when your device is connected??

Comment: No, i have XCode 4.6 only. Since i am running mac OS 10.7.5 which is not supported for XCode 5

Comment: Thank you :) Before posting question it was in my mind that bundle of people will down vote at first sight but to me its more important to know the reason :)